# Sequence of errors in mobile app: [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script Error; markup://native:AuraPrimingService: undefined; [SmartStoreAdapterError:

Tags: mobilesdk

About 10 days ago all of our mobile users started seeing the same sequence of errors. They are all on iphone 7 and most are on the latest iOS and the latest Salesforce app version. The errors have been completely blocking users from using the Salesforce apps. The errors also didn't coincide with any updates to the apps on our end. The errors show up pretty rapidly in sequence and the page behind is rapidly refreshing. We are trying to understand what this error even means.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFyIb.jpg)

[image]